# Windows GDI libraries not included after adding x64 to my project

Tags: visual-studio, linker

I have a working win32 project that I'm trying to add an x64 platform build to.  I've got the x64 build working by allowing Visual Studio 2013 to 'copy it from the win32 settings' and tweaking the results to get it to work.  But in the process, something happened to make the win32 version no longer include all of the windows libraries.

When I diff the build commands for the win32 project from the .log files generated before and after adding the x64 platform, all the compiler and linker commands from the 2 logs are identical except for the lists of libraries included in the linker commands:

The Win32 link command includes these libraries before adding x64:

```
lz32.lib wsock32.lib odbc32.lib odbc cp32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMTD /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
```

After adding x64, it only includes the first 4:

```
lz32.lib wsock32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMTD NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
```

Those first 4 libraries are explicitly included as  in both the before and after vcxproj files:

```
<AdditionalDependencies>lz32.lib;wsock32.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
```

And the rest of the libraries are not mentioned specifically in either the before or after vcxproj files.  There are no specific errors in the 'after' log compalining about bad or wrong versions of those libraries - they're simply not included.  As far as I know, no changes have been made to the win32 sections of the vcxproj file, so what could have caused the windows libraries to have been left out?  Or better yet, what normally causes them to be included?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I found it.  Somewhere along the line, when I was editing my vcxproj file to get the X64 configuration to build, I accidentally changed the AdditionalDependencies macro inclusions for my win32 builds from using %() notation to wrongly using $(), causing the built-in standard dependencies from being ignored.  Sorry for the stupid question:

```
C:\ROBY>diff win32proj.txt x64proj.txt
69c69
<       <AdditionalDependencies>lz32.lib;wsock32.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;**%**(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
---
>       <AdditionalDependencies>lz32.lib;wsock32.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;**$**(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
```